# cron job: CodeIgniter2+Doctrine2 How do I get this to work?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, cron, codeigniter-2

I am attempting to use cron to run a PHP file that executes a series of actions.  I've done this before with simple procedural PHP, the trick then was doing the cron like this:

> /usr/local/php5/bin/php /home/me/fullpath/turnrun.php

and having this at the very top of the PHP file I wanted executed.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
```

I'm using CodeIgniter 2 and Doctrine 2, so I have controllers and classes and all kinds of fancy stuff now, and I can't figure out how to make this work.

When I attempt to run a 'backend_test_turn.php' file I get an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/me/fullpath/application/controllers/backend_test_turn.php
>   on line 59

This file includes

```
class Backend_test_turn extends CI_Controller {

    // code

    $logmsg = new ORM\Dynasties2\Systemlog;   // <---  this is line 59

    // code

}
```

Note that when I run this normally (in a browser), the code works fine and does not throw an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the controller code directly from command line like this:

```
php index.php Backend_test_turn/action/data
```

OR

```
php index.php Backend_test_turn action data
```

You can find more help [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$logmsg = new ORM\Dynasties2\Systemlog;
$logmsg = new ORM\Dynasties2\Systemlog(); // <- see difference
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use CURL instead?

I have an application CI & Doctrine with CRON jobs and I've got many errors like yours while trying to launch controllers via CLI.

Personnaly now I use CURL instead of CI CLI and it works like a charm.